# Generar .zip dinámico y descargar

Tags: php, zip

tengo un problema, resulta que hice este script para generar una descarga en una pagina web. en mi servidor usando WAMP server (bajo windows) funciona perfecto, pero en el servidor con CentOS no funciona, estoy usando la misma versión de PHP la 5.6.25 .

Aqui le paso mi codigo:

```
<?php
//esconder notificaciones
@ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL & ~ E_NOTICE);
//que el server no comprima
@apache_setenv('no-gzip', 1);
@ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');
ignore_user_abort(true);
if (isset($_GET["id"])) {
    // Creamos un instancia de la clase ZipArchive
    $conexion=mysqli_connect("localhost","usuario","contraseña","baseDeDatos") 
    or die("Problemas en la conexion");
    $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion,$_GET["id"]);
    $result = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM `subidas` WHERE `ID` = '$id'");
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 && mysqli_num_rows($result) < 2) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $archivos = explode("/:/", $row["Archivos"]);
            $ID = $row["ID"];
        }
        $zip = new ZipArchive();
        // Creamos y abrimos un archivo zip temporal
        $zip->open($ID.".zip",ZipArchive::CREATE);// Añadimos un directorio
        $dir = 'archivos';
        $zip->addEmptyDir($dir);
        // Añadimos un archivo en la raid del zip.
        //$zip->addFile("imagen1.jpg","mi_imagen1.jpg");
        foreach ($archivos as $value) {
            if ($value != "") {
                $archivo = explode("///", $value);
                //Añadimos un archivo dentro del directorio que hemos creado
                $zip->addFile("../uploads/".$archivo[0],$dir."/".$archivo[1]);
            }
        }
        // Una vez añadido los archivos deseados cerramos el zip.
        $zip->close();
        // parsear el nombre del archivo
        $path_parts = pathinfo($ID.".zip");
        $file_name  = $path_parts['basename'];
        $file_ext   = $path_parts['extension'];
        $file_path  = $ID.".zip"; //Si se descarga de otra ubicación, cambiar por: $file_path = './carpeta/descargas/' . $file_name;

        $is_attachment = true; //Como adjunto (cambiar a false si es un stream, por ej. audio o video)

        // existe el archivo?
        if (is_file($file_path))
        {
            $file_size  = filesize($file_path);
            $file = @fopen($file_path,"rb");
            if ($file)
            {
                // encabezados, y sin caché
                header("Pragma: public");
                header("Expires: -1");
                header("Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");

                if ($is_attachment)
                        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file_name\"");
                else
                        header('Content-Disposition: inline;');

                // mime type según la extensión (agregar otra si falta)
                $ctype_default = "application/octet-stream";
                $content_types = array(
                        "exe" => "application/octet-stream",
                        "zip" => "application/zip",
                        "mp3" => "audio/mpeg",
                        "mpg" => "video/mpeg",
                        "avi" => "video/x-msvideo",
                );
                $ctype = isset($content_types[$file_ext]) ? $content_types[$file_ext] : $ctype_default;
                header("Content-Type: " . $ctype);

                // http_range si hay gestión de descarga
                $range = '';
                if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']))
                {
                    list($size_unit, $range_orig) = explode('=', $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], 2);
                    if ($size_unit == 'bytes')
                    {
                        list($range, $extra_ranges) = explode(',', $range_orig, 2);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
                        exit;
                    }
                }
                list($seek_start, $seek_end) = explode('-', $range, 2);
                $seek_end   = (empty($seek_end)) ? ($file_size - 1) : min(abs(intval($seek_end)),($file_size - 1));
                $seek_start = (empty($seek_start) || $seek_end < abs(intval($seek_start))) ? 0 : max(abs(intval($seek_start)),0);
                if ($seek_start > 0 || $seek_end < ($file_size - 1))
                {
                    header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content');
                    header('Content-Range: bytes '.$seek_start.'-'.$seek_end.'/'.$file_size);
                    header('Content-Length: '.($seek_end - $seek_start + 1));
                }
                else
                  header("Content-Length: $file_size");

                header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

                ignore_user_abort(true);

                set_time_limit(0);
                fseek($file, $seek_start);

                $chunksize = 1*(1024*1024); // how many bytes per chunk 

                // imprimir el archivo
                while(!feof($file)) 
                {
                    print(@fread($file, $chunksize));     //leer 8KB
                    ob_flush();
                    flush();
                    sleep(1);
                    if (connection_aborted()) 
                    {
                                @fclose($file);
                                @unlink($ID.".zip");//Destruye archivo temporal
                        exit; //error
                    }
                }

                // terminó OK
                //@fclose($file);
            }
            else 
            {
                // no se pudo abrir el archivo
                header("HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // no existe el archivo
            header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
        }
        //todo OK
        @fclose($file);
        @unlink($ID.".zip");//Destruye archivo temporal
        exit;
    } else {
        header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
    }
} else {
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
}
?>
```

me tira el siguiente error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

el modulo zip se encuentra habilitado[image: modulo php_zip]

permisos de la carpeta PHP:[image: permisos]

alguna idea de que estoy haciendo mal? muchas gracias!!

Comment: ¿Que error interno te da el servidor?

Comment: @Lithorell gracias por interesarte, no soy muy bueno en esto aún. no logre conseguir ningún otro error. probé comentando la primera linea que esconde las notificaciones y todos los headers, y algunas otras cosas para ver si lograba que php me tire agun error extra, pero solo logre que cambie de 500 a 404.

Comment: @Kenneth verifica los permisos en la carpeta que esta guardando

Comment: @JackNavaRow y como hago eso?

Comment: en linux  ls -ls, casi seguro que tu problema son permisos de usuarios

Comment: ejecute el comando `chmod 777 PHP` y la carpeta quedo con todos los permisos, pero ahora me tira error en todos los archivos php que hay dentro. el mismo error 500

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Revisa que tengas habilitado en tu Cpanel la Extenció php_zip.dll

Modifica tu código por este:

```
   <?php

//que el server no comprima
@apache_setenv('no-gzip', 1);
@ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');
ignore_user_abort(true);
if (isset($_GET["id"])) {
    // Creamos un instancia de la clase ZipArchive
    $conexion=mysqli_connect("localhost","usuario","contraseña","baseDeDatos") 
    or die("Problemas en la conexion");
    $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion,$_GET["id"]);
    $result = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM `subidas` WHERE `ID` = '$id'");
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 && mysqli_num_rows($result) < 2) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $archivos = explode("/:/", $row["Archivos"]);
            $ID = $row["ID"];
        }
        $zip = new ZipArchive();
        // Creamos y abrimos un archivo zip temporal
        $zip->open($ID.".zip",ZipArchive::CREATE);// Añadimos un directorio
        $dir = 'archivos';
        $zip->addEmptyDir($dir);
        // Añadimos un archivo en la raid del zip.
        //$zip->addFile("imagen1.jpg","mi_imagen1.jpg");
        foreach ($archivos as $value) {
            if ($value != "") {
                $archivo = explode("///", $value);
                //Añadimos un archivo dentro del directorio que hemos creado
                $zip->addFile("../uploads/".$archivo[0],$dir."/".$archivo[1]);
            }
        }
        // Una vez añadido los archivos deseados cerramos el zip.
        $zip->close();
}
}
```

Y dime si se crea el archivo.

Comment: uso el CentOS webpanel, y si esta habilitado. :/

Comment: revisa en los archivos del servidor si no se te genero un archivo "error_php" o un archivo plano que diga error, puede que hay este mas detallado el error que se te presenta

Comment: Revisando tu código, parece que el error puedes tenerlo en esta linea: $file = @fopen($file_path,"rb");  Tu condición deberias cambiarla por if ($file_size>0) {  | Pruebalo y me cuentas

Comment: gracias por responder andres, el archivo donde puede estar?

Comment: @Andrés esto es un comentario y se ve muy mal en la comunidad te recomiendo eliminar esta publicacion

Comment: y como corregiría esa linea?

Comment: @jackNavaRow, entiendo lo que dices, pero la pagina aun no me deja poner comentario, entonces me toca comentar en la parte de respuesta. Kenneth el archivo siempre se genera en la misma carpeta donde donde se presenta el error, en este caso, donde tienes el archivo que genera el zip, pregunta, el Zip si se genera? | la linea seria // existe el archivo?
        if (is_file($file_path))
        {
            $file_size  = filesize($file_path);
            $file = @fopen($file_path,"rb");
            if ($file_size > 0)
            {  // Pruebalo y nos cuentas

Comment: @Andrés todos pasamos por eso!, ten paciencia trata de terminar de ayudarlo y mejora la respuesta , si esta pregunta la dejas aqui te van a puntuar negativo

Comment: @Andrés probé con esa linea, pero sigue igual. y el archivo no se genera.

Comment: Te sigue saliendo el mensaje de HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error?

Comment: si, estoy intentando lo que dijo @JackNavaRow de los permisos, pero como se poco y nada de linux, me estoy demorando un poco jeje

Comment: dime que usuario tiene la carpeta si es root o no existe la carpeta tendras inconvenientes

Comment: Utiliza el código que te deje en la respuesta y me comentas si se crea el archivo o que error te aparece

Comment: probé con el código, pero no se creó el archivo. para volver a poder ejecutar los scripts de PHP tuve que ejecutar chmod 755 PHP (php es la carpeta con todos los scripts de PHP, dentro de la misma debería crearse el archivo zip, esta mal que se cree en la misma carpeta?)

Comment: @JackNavaRow como obtengo esa informacion que me pedis? la carpeta existe

Comment: la carpeta tiene permisos, chequea el usuario ahora generalmente el usuario deberia ser www-data investiga acerca del chown

Comment: Hola @kenneth , aun no tengo puntos como para comentar tu publicación xD jaja, asi que me toco por acá, prueba descomentando el    ignore_user_abort(true); y dentro de la condición if (connection_aborted()) 
                    {
                                break;
                    } Agregas el break y me cuentas si te funciono.

Comment: no entiendo, agrego el break antes de @fclose($file); o despues de exit; o reemplazo las 3 lineas con el break;?

Comment: después de una meditación profunda me di cuenta que tenia que reemplazar las 3 lineas por el break; y funcionó perfecto! muchísimas gracias!

Comment: Jajajaja disculpa por no responderte antes, me había ocupado me alegra que te haya funcionado.

Answer (score 1):

Bueno, después de mucho intentar lo solucioné de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php
//esconder notificaciones
//@ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL & ~ E_NOTICE);
//que el server no comprima
//@apache_setenv('no-gzip', 1);
//@ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');
//ignore_user_abort(true);
if (isset($_GET["id"])) {
    // Creamos un instancia de la clase ZipArchive
    $conexion=mysqli_connect("localhost","usuario","contraseña","base") 
    or die("Problemas en la conexion");
    $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion,$_GET["id"]);
    $result = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM `subidas` WHERE `ID` = '$id'");
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 && mysqli_num_rows($result) < 2) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $archivos = explode("/:/", $row["Archivos"]);
            $ID = $row["ID"];
        }
        $directorio = "../temp/";
        if(!file_exists($directorio)){
            mkdir($directorio);
            chmod($directorio,0777);
        }
        $zip = new ZipArchive();
        // Creamos y abrimos un archivo zip temporal
        $zip->open($directorio.$ID.".zip",ZipArchive::CREATE);// Añadimos un directorio
        $dir = 'archivos';
        $zip->addEmptyDir($dir);
        // Añadimos un archivo en la raid del zip.
        //$zip->addFile("imagen1.jpg","mi_imagen1.jpg");
        foreach ($archivos as $value) {
            if ($value != "") {
                $archivo = explode("///", $value);
                //Añadimos un archivo dentro del directorio que hemos creado
                $zip->addFile("../uploads/".$archivo[0],$dir."/".$archivo[1]);
            }
        }
        // Una vez añadido los archivos deseados cerramos el zip.
        $zip->close();
        // parsear el nombre del archivo
        $path_parts = pathinfo($ID.".zip");
        $file_name  = $path_parts['basename'];
        $file_ext   = $path_parts['extension'];
        $file_path  = $directorio.$ID.".zip"; //Si se descarga de otra ubicación, cambiar por: $file_path = './carpeta/descargas/' . $file_name;
        chmod($file_path,0777);
        $is_attachment = true; //Como adjunto (cambiar a false si es un stream, por ej. audio o video)

        // existe el archivo?
        if (is_file($file_path))
        {
            $file_size  = filesize($file_path);
            $file = @fopen($file_path,"rb");
            if ($file)
            {
                // encabezados, y sin caché
                header("Pragma: public");
                header("Expires: -1");
                header("Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");

                if ($is_attachment)
                        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file_name\"");
                else
                        header('Content-Disposition: inline;');

                // mime type según la extensión (agregar otra si falta)
                $ctype_default = "application/octet-stream";
                $content_types = array(
                        "exe" => "application/octet-stream",
                        "zip" => "application/zip",
                        "mp3" => "audio/mpeg",
                        "mpg" => "video/mpeg",
                        "avi" => "video/x-msvideo",
                );
                $ctype = isset($content_types[$file_ext]) ? $content_types[$file_ext] : $ctype_default;
                header("Content-Type: " . $ctype);

                // http_range si hay gestión de descarga
                $range = '';
                if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']))
                {
                    list($size_unit, $range_orig) = explode('=', $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], 2);
                    if ($size_unit == 'bytes')
                    {
                        list($range, $extra_ranges) = explode(',', $range_orig, 2);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
                        exit;
                    }
                }
                list($seek_start, $seek_end) = explode('-', $range, 2);
                $seek_end   = (empty($seek_end)) ? ($file_size - 1) : min(abs(intval($seek_end)),($file_size - 1));
                $seek_start = (empty($seek_start) || $seek_end < abs(intval($seek_start))) ? 0 : max(abs(intval($seek_start)),0);
                if ($seek_start > 0 || $seek_end < ($file_size - 1))
                {
                    header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content');
                    header('Content-Range: bytes '.$seek_start.'-'.$seek_end.'/'.$file_size);
                    header('Content-Length: '.($seek_end - $seek_start + 1));
                }
                else
                  header("Content-Length: $file_size");

                header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

                ignore_user_abort(true);

                set_time_limit(0);
                fseek($file, $seek_start);

                $chunksize = 1*(1024*1024); // how many bytes per chunk 

                // imprimir el archivo
                while(!feof($file)) 
                {
                    print(@fread($file, $chunksize));     //leer 8KB
                    ob_flush();
                    flush();
                    sleep(1);
                    if (connection_aborted()) 
                    {
                                @fclose($file);
                                @unlink($file_path);//Destruye archivo temporal
                        exit; //error
                    }
                }

                // terminó OK
                @fclose($file);
                @unlink($file_path);//Destruye archivo temporal
                exit;
            }
            else 
            {
                // no se pudo abrir el archivo
                header("HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // no existe el archivo
            header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
        }
    } else {
        header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
    }
} else {
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
}
?>
```

funciona perfecto excepto que no borra el archivo zip creado temporalmente luego de la descarga. para que lo borre, tengo entendido que tengo que descomentar esta linea:

```
//ignore_user_abort(true);
```

sin embargo, cuando la descomento e intento descargar el archivo, el mimso se descarga, pero se cuelga la pagina, deja de responder todo por unos 5 min. aprox. el archivo ZIP se borra. 
alguna idea de que estoy haciendo mal? Muchas Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Para que se borre usas ésta línea:

```
unlink(_fileName_);
```

Comment: Podrias explicar mejor el ejemplo y tomar el codigo que esta en la pregunta de preferencia